# NSDateFormatter +dateFormatFromTemplate:options:locale: BUG?

Tags: iphone, nsdateformatter

Please see below codes and output.

```
 NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
 [dateComponents setYear:2011];
 [dateComponents setMonth:1];
 [dateComponents setDay:1];

 NSDate *date = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:dateComponents];

 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:[NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"YYYYMMMd" options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]]];

 NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

 NSLog(@"Happy New Year: %@", dateString);
```

What do you expect for output?

```
 Happy New Year: Jan 1, 2011
```

But the result is...

```
 Happy New Year: Jan 1, 2010
```

What's wrong? Please help...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The template format string should be `@"yyyyMMMd"` (lowercase "y" for year).

Uppercase "Y" is something else (see [Unicode Date Format Patterns](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns)).

Comment: +1 Specifically, Y is the year of the current week. The week of January 1, 2011 belongs to 2010, so YYYY produces 2010.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw: Thanks.  I should have pointed out the difference in the answer because it can be confusing since "Y" seems to "work" most of the time.  Uppercase "Y" tells you what year the week containing your date starts in.  So if Jan 1 is on a Thursday, "Y" will give the year of the *start* of that week (ie. Monday).  For Jan 7 or later, "Y" will give the same result as "y" but of course it's better to use the right formatting letter in the first place.

Comment: @Anna: I think, to be precise, Y gives you the year that goes with some "week number". So 31 dec can be part of week 1 of the next year, and thus Y can give you the next year (although the week *starts* in the current year)