# Creating NSDate from month, day and year

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I want to create a NSDate variable from a string, that date is coming from third party server so i cannot change it. the date is in this format **December 08, 2013** and i am using given below date formater style to convert it into date but that is creating a wrong and fixed date for all items which is **2012-12-22 19:00:00 +0000**

Will you please guide me how to solve this problem. i donot want break string and use NSDateComponents to create date.

```
[dateFormaterForSermonTemp setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, YYYY"];
```

Comment: Don't use uppercase YYYY.  Use lowercase yyyy.

Comment: And note that the resulting NSDate object will *always* display in the format you show above, and in GMT -- you cannot change that format.  If you want to display in a different format run the date back through an NSDateFormatter to produce a string.  (In fact, you should never use the format produced by `@"%@"` on an NSDate, as that is for diagnostics only and can, in theory, change at any time.)

Comment: @Anna what is difference between YYYY and yyyy

Comment: @Developer, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467173/nsdateformatter-dateformatfromtemplateoptionslocale-bug and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133549/difference-between-yyyy-and-yyyy-in-nsdateformatter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following code :

```
NSString *stringDate = @"December 08, 2013";

// Convert string to date object
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM dd, yyyy"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:stringDate];

// Convert date object to desired output format
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, yyyy"];
stringDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];

NSLog(@"%@", stringDate);
```

`stringDate` is the string from your server, you convert it to a `NSDate` and you add a new format for the date like `@"MMMM dd, yyyy"`.

(Here, you will have the same result but change the format like `@"MMMM-dd-yyyy EEE"` for example to get another format date).

**EDIT :**

Maybe you need to set the timeZome for your date

```
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT+0:00"]];
```

Comment: yes its working but it changes date to one day back output is 2013-12-07 19:00:00 +0000

Comment: I think you have a problem with the clock settings on your device or with the timeZone. Have a look to my edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM dd, yyyy"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"December 08, 2013"];
```

Comment: yes its working but it changes date to one day back output is 2013-12-07 19:00:00 +0000

Answer (score 0):

Here you have [documentation about date format string](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns). (the rod not the fish).

So your format string for date **December 08, 2013** should be something like (the fish):

```
@"MMMM dd, y"
```

and don't forget to set proper locale for the date formater or you can have unexpected problems on devices with different locale settings.

Comment: The critical thing is the lower-case "y".  Upper-case "Y" has an oddly different meaning that mucks up everything.

Comment: see my link, documentation is blurry how capital `Y` works in format string. It says it is used in "year-week calendar" so week information probably is required to make capital `Y` work properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *strDate=@"December 08, 2013";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];

NSDate *date=[dateFormatter dateFromString:strDate];
```

Try this...

Comment: yes its working but it changes date to one day back output is 2013-12-07 19:00:00 +0000